# Append image from array to HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying make buttons to append images to HTML from array. Why the first snippet  doesn't work?

First snippet with array doesn't work

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const dir = fs.readdirSync('/Files/Изображение').filter(files => files.endsWith('.png'))

let imag = dir[0];

function createImgBlock() {
    const imgBlocks = document.createElement('img');
    imgBlocks.src = '/Files/Изображение/' + dir[0];
    document.body.append(imgBlocks);
}
```

Second snippet only with the name of image is work

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const dir = fs.readdirSync('/Files/Изображение').filter(files => files.endsWith('.png'))

let imag = dir[0];

function createImgBlock() {
    const imgBlocks = document.createElement('img');
    imgBlocks.src = '/Files/Изображение/' + '1407916_900_600.png';
    document.body.append(imgBlocks);
}
```

Comment: Client-side JS doesn't have access to `fs`, and nodeJs doesn't have access to `document`, so it's not really clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Andy it's not work even without fs

Comment: imgBlocks.src = im[0]

Comment: just array doesn't work